# What does it mean for Caenorhabditis species to be "pseudoparasitic"?

Tags: ecology, parasitology, parasitism, host-pathogen-interaction

In this [Wormbook chapter](http://wormbook.org/chapters/www_ecolCaenorhabditis/ecolCaenorhabditis.html), Kiontke says that some *Caenorhabditis* species live "pseudoparasitically" on warm-blooded animals. What does it mean? What is a pseudoparasite? I understand a parasite to be in association with a host where the relationship is beneficial for the parasite and harmful for the host. How is pseudoparasitism defined?

I have found several definition:

- [Something in the blood that is mistaken for a parasite](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/pseudoparasite): not applicable to *Ceanorhabditis* as no *Caenorhabditis* has ever been found alive in blood
- [A false parasite; may be either a commensal or a temporary parasite (the latter is an organism accidentally ingested and surviving briefly in the intestine)](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/pseudoparasite)): could be this
- [an object or organism that resembles or is mistaken for a parasite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/pseudoparasite): could be this
- [interpreted to be parasitic but not actually parasitic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pseudoparasite): could be this
- [This](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Pseudoparasites) definition actually sounds like the definition of a parasite and only applies to invertebrates, so not applicable to *Ceanorhabditis*

In conclusion, I would say that some *Caenorhabditis* are pseudoparasitic of warm-blooded animals, which means they are commensal and cause no harm. However, I don't see the point of saying they are pseudoparasitic. I would rather just say commensal.

Comment: It might just be my opinion, but I think part of the issue approximates something like: The more you know about a subject, the pickier you become about how you would describe something. I remember this being true in undergrad calculus, when the professor would lay out a concept, but also hint that it's not the full picture because of more advanced concepts that they knew, and we couldn't know unless we pursued a PhD in Mathematics.

Comment: Why don’t you Email the authors themselves?  When I contacted Walter Sudhaus many years ago he was very helpful.